# SyncService onCreate called all the time during sync

Tags: android, performance, android-syncadapter

I just started working on an Android app that has some big performance issues during sync. There was some low hanging fruit, like doing repeated `insert` instead of `bulkInsert` and the like, but I also noticed the following in the logs:

```
11-25 11:46:02.630 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: onCreate()
11-25 11:46:02.630 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: Bound
11-25 11:46:02.660 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: onCreate()
11-25 11:46:02.660 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: Bound
11-25 11:46:02.700 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: onCreate()
11-25 11:46:02.700 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: Bound
11-25 11:46:02.720 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: onCreate()
11-25 11:46:02.720 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: Bound
11-25 11:46:02.750 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: onCreate()
11-25 11:46:02.750 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: Bound
11-25 11:46:02.780 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: onCreate()
11-25 11:46:02.780 10160-10160/my.package.name:sync D/mlt_SyncService: Bound
```

...and so on and on...
This is the Service in question:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "mlt_SyncService";

    private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;
    // Object to use as a thread-safe lock
    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
                sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onCreate()");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Bound");
        return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

Nothing special going on there. However, it seems like the new SyncService is instantiated all the time. The only service usage I can find is in the manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name="my.package.name.sync.SyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

Again, nothing special there.

It seems like the `SyncService` is instantiated on each entity saved, but going through that code didn't reveal anything suspicious, other than the fact that we're doing a one by one `insert` instead of a `bulkInsert` but that's a different story. Also, even when I put in a breakpoint and stop `insert` execution the `onCreate()` log stream continues.

I thought that maybe there are content observers which trigger a new sync on change, but there's none of that. There is only one `requestSync` call; in the `onClick` listener.

So, why is my SyncService getting instantiated and bound all the time during sync?

Thanks for any ideas.